If $\frak{a}$ is a proper ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, then $\bigcap_{i\geq 1} \frak{a}$ $^i =\{0 \}$.
I am reading these notes on the Kronecker-Weber theorem. On page 9, they quote without proof the theorem:

If $\frak{a}$ is a proper ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, then
$\bigcap_{i\geq 1} \frak{a}$$^i =\{0 \}$.

Does anyone know what this theorem is called or where I can find a proof? It looks very similar to the Krull Intersection Theorem.

if $a$ is a nonzero element of the intersection then $(a)$ is divisible by all powers of $\mathfrak a$, which contradicts the unique factorization to prime ideals in $\mathcal O_K$. But maybe you want a proof not using factorization to primes.

See Krull's intersection theorem

@user8268 This is perfect thankyou!

We can suppose $\mathfrak a \not= (0)$, since the result is obvious when $\mathfrak a = (0)$. Set $\mathfrak b = \bigcap_{i \geq 1} \mathfrak a$. Since $\mathfrak b \subset \mathfrak a$, $\mathfrak b$ is a proper ideal. To prove $\mathfrak b = (0)$, we'll assume $\mathfrak b \not= (0)$ and get a contradiction.
Every nonzero proper ideal has a prime ideal factor.  Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal dividing $\mathfrak a$. Then for all $i \geq 1$, $\mathfrak b \subset \mathfrak a^i \subset \mathfrak p^i$, so $\mathfrak p^i \mid \mathfrak b$. Thus $\mathfrak b$ is divisible by arbitrarily higher powers of $\mathfrak p$. That is impossible in $\mathcal O_K$, so we have a contradiction and thus $\mathfrak b = (0)$.
